# jupyterhub protect source code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, jupyter

I developed some Python modules that I would like to make available for people to use, but not to see the source code or download it. The ideal setting would be a free service where people could run it on Amazon EC2 or Google Cloud. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want people to import your modules or do you want them to access them through an API or a webpage?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your code in Google Cloud, then after the [free trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions#free-trial) you can use [always free tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/), which will allow you to run this service continuously, but within some limits.

For example under always free tier you can use [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) and it will provide up to 28 instance hours a day. With 28 instance hours you can run one instance 24 hours a day with an additional instance when it's necessary(up to 4 hours), or 28 instances for an hour a day. You may also provide access to your application through an [API](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks).